# How to assign each variable in a vector of variables new value using loop?

Tags: r

I want to assign variables a new value using a loop. Say I have N variables v1 through vN. They have some value stored already. I want to update the stored values by passing them to a function and store in the same variable. Something like:

```
v1 <- "value1"
v2 <- "value2"
.
.
.
vN <- "valueN"

v_vector <- c(v1,v2,v3,...,vN)

dummy_function <- function(x){paste("new",x)}

for (v in v_vector){
  v <- dummy_function(v) 
}
```

This should update the value of `v1` to `new value1`, for example. How can I achieve this in R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we already created the vector objects, get them into a `list` and apply the function, and update the original objects with `list2env`

```
list2env(lapply(mget(ls(pattern = '^v\\d+$')), dummy_function), .GlobalEnv)
```